# How should we assess the quality of steganography?

Tags: steganography

I am asking this question instead of extending the discussion of another question ([Perfect Steganography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/62447/perfect-steganography/64686#64686)).  I did try starting a chat room (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87636/perfect-steganography) but nobody knew about it ;-(.

I *think* that I have achieved near perfect steganography

This is an exceptional claim and should be accompanied by exceptional proof, but I am at a loss as to how to quantify/prove this claim.  I am asking for help with this validation - a refutation would be an acceptable outcome to this question.

The basic method is as follows: The bulk of the image data in the file represents coefficients to the DC algorithm.  These coefficients are routinely pruned to reduce the size and resolution of the image according to the needs of the image compressor.  The level of compression is typically constant across an image, and is chosen for its effect upon size/quality rather than on a rigourously defined process. Indeed many programs use a default quality setting, or allow selection of one of a number of predetermined quality settings.  These settings have different levels of effect on different parts of the image.

By modulating the quality of the image as the image data is traversed I can create a signal that can be interpreted as an array of bytes.  I call this the payload.  (The method has a few subtleties that might best be left for offline discussion.)

The byte array payload from an unmodified jpeg is effectively 'random'. By 'random' here I mean that there is no apparent order - the data is obviously not random as it is related to the image - but the relationship is so indirect as to be ignorable.  By replacing some of the bytes with an encrypted message (effectively more 'random' data) we can hide the message without increasing the apparent order (decreasing the apparent entropy).

As an example here are three versions of the same image one with no payload, one with a short message ("hello World"), and one with the first sentence of 'Lorem Ipsum'

- http://vanleersum.uk/downloads/images/Drawing1.jpg
- http://vanleersum.uk/downloads/images/Drawing2.jpg
- http://vanleersum.uk/downloads/images/Drawing3.jpg

I cannot see a difference, and I would welcome proof that a difference is detectable.  Do not be fooled by the sizes.  The modulation of quality is as likely to reduce the size of the image as it is to increase it.

As a further illustration here are two images:

- http://vanleersum.uk/downloads/images/eraseWithZeroes.jpg
- http://vanleersum.uk/downloads/images/eraseWithFF.jpg

Where the normally 'random' payload has been set to all ones (FF) or all zeroes.  I would like to emphasise that this is **not** an encrypted message containing all ones or zeroes, but the underlying byte array that is inserted into the image. This is the most extreme variation I can imagine in the data, but the effect upon the image is negligeable.....

Now, showing you images is no proof at all.  So I provide two apps to play with:

- http://vanleersum.uk/downloads/SmugglerMac.dmg  for MacOS
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.vanleersum.smugglerandroid for android phones.

**Please can you suggest other ways to test my claim?**

Notes as answers to comments:

- None of the data involved is truly random.  Every change to every bit has a theoretically determinable effect upon the image. However the variations in the data that lead to variations from the original are all within the variations that could be expected in the output from some unknown but compliant jpeg compressor (or even the same compressor with slightly different settings).
- I guess that perfection would require that an examiner with the original and the modified would see no difference.  I do not think that this is easily achievable in my scheme. Any change to any bit of any byte can be detected by a byte compare. So can I limit this discussion to whether the modified file in isolation can be shown to differ from the expected format in a way that would indicate that it contains a message?

Comment: empirical testing is no proof either

Comment: _By 'random' here I mean that there is no apparent order_ For the steganography to be "perfect", you need to prove with absolute certainty that the background noise you are blending in to is completely random and 100% unpredictable by any means, and that any bias in it can be mimiced perfectly by your steganography.

Comment: @forest "Perfect" is trivially proved with .BMP stego.      The lower bit(s) of all photographs are truly random due to quantum sensor and quantization effects.  All properly encrypted messages are indistinguishable from random.     If message entropy < noise entropy, you get perfect stego.      Simples.

Comment: @PaulUszak I would love to see your proof that the LSBs are 1) unbiased, 2) uniformly distributed, and 3) impossible to predict even in theory.

Comment: @forest I don't think that any evidence I can offer here will convince you. Can I suggest that you  take this (off topic here) discussion to the Photography forum, and ask "Why are my photos noisy?"

Comment: @PaulUszak Then you do not have trivial proof. And yes, I know what causes photoelectric noise, and I also know it is not perfectly uniformly distributed and _can_ be distinguished from a uniform random stream.

Comment: @PaulUszak Can I assume that 'perfect' excludes the case where the original is available for comparison? I had not considered that, but it would neatly make 'perfection' unattainable.

Comment: @kodlu  True, but without a demonstration of the effectiveness there would be little interest in examining the somewhat arcane implementation details to discover if there is a mathematical proof in this instance.

Comment: I don't think that the definition of successful stego includes the 100% indistinguishability of two images, one of which carries the message.  That's clearly impossible.       And don't forget, all original photographs are unique, even of exactly the same scene under exactly the same lighting conditions.   You surely know this having worked with stego. Perfection would be the inability to confirm that any single photograph contains a message without knowing the encryption key. That's easily done for BMPs with small message entropy. Probably JPGs too.

Comment: "That's easily done for BMPs with small message entropy." That's certainly open to discussion - it's kind of stating that it can be proven without actually proving it. I'm not sure what you mean with "message entropy". Before we get into extended discussions however, remember that the question is asking for a way to assess quality of stenography. If perfect stenography can exist is another - previously asked - question.